# Composite C1 - nopCommerce integration

Tags: nopcommerce, c1-cms

I am following the step by step instructions (http://docs.composite.net/Packages/Commerce/NopCommerce) for integrating the nopCommerce module into the Composite C1 CMS but have been halted when trying to perform step 2 when converting the files.

```
"Run the Composite.Commerce.nopCommerce.Convertor.exe from the command prompt redirecting its output to Handlers.xml like this:
C:\nopFiles\Composite.Commerce.nopCommerce.Convertor.exe > Handlers.xml"
```

When I try to do this I receive an "Access is denied" message and the process does not run.  Has anyone else experienced this issue when trying to integrate the two?

Answer (score 0):

TGuimond,
please try [run CMD as Administrator](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/), and than from CMD run your command "C:\nopFiles\Composite.Commerce.nopCommerce.Convertor.exe > Handlers.xml"